# term and range filter in elasticsearch can't work

Tags: filter, elasticsearch

I have a record

viewCount:300000000
author: psy

but I can't search this record

How can I fix my code?

```
{ "query":{
 "filtered" :{
     "filter" :{ 
        "and":[{"term" :{"author": "psy"}},
               {"range" :{"viewCount" :{ "gte" : 3000000 }}}] },
      "query":{ 
         "multi_match" : { "query" : "psy", "fields" : ["title","content"] } } } },
               "size": 20 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure from what you posted, but the problem seems to be in the `"query"` part of the code you posted. When I saved the document you posted (at least what I assume you meant), and ran your search query, it wasn't returned. But when I removed the `"query"` part and just ran the `"filter"` part, the document was returned. More precisely, I created an index and added the document:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "viewCount": 300000000,
   "author": "psy"
}
```

then ran your filtered query:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {
                  "term": {
                     "author": "psy"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "range": {
                     "viewCount": {
                        "gte": 3000000
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         "query": {
            "multi_match": {
               "query": "psy",
               "fields": [
                  "title",
                  "content"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 20
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

and got nothing. When I ran just the `"query"` part:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "multi_match": {
         "query": "psy",
         "fields": [
            "title",
            "content"
         ]
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

I also got nothing. But when I ran just the `"filter"` part:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "filter": {
      "and": [
         {
            "term": {
               "author": "psy"
            }
         },
         {
            "range": {
               "viewCount": {
                  "gte": 3000000
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "viewCount": 300000000,
               "author": "psy"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

the document was returned. So something is wrong here:

```
"query": {
    "multi_match": {
       "query": "psy",
       "fields": [
          "title",
          "content"
       ]
    }
}
```

Since the document I have doesn't contain those fields, it does not match the query and is not returned. Maybe your docs have those fields, but without a little more information about your setup it's hard to tell you what is going wrong. Maybe if you posted the mapping and a few example documents it would help.